State.something.push() dosent work in react-redux
Iam new to react-redux and iam unable to determine what the error actually is. The error i get is state.lectures.push is not a function but the data is sent to the server and to the database and i can retrieve it too and also the data is being updated in frontend when i refresh. Only the annoying part is that it is not rendering properly.
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
const initialState={
  lectures:[],
}
export const addLecture = createAsyncThunk(
  "addLecture",
  async ({ c_id, formData }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/addLecture/${c_id}`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        credentials: "include",
      });
      const resdata = await response.json();
      console.log(resdata);
      return resdata;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);

export const getLectures = createAsyncThunk("getLectures", async (id) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/getLectures/${id}`, {
      credentials: "include",
    });
    const res = await response.json();
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

export const RecordSlice = createSlice({
  name: "lecture",
  initialState,
  reducers:{},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(addLecture.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.lectures.push(action.payload)
      console.log(action.payload);
    });
    builder.addCase(addLecture.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.log("error", action.payload);
    });
    builder.addCase(getLectures.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.lectures=action.payload;
        console.log(action.payload);
      });
      builder.addCase(getLectures.rejected, (state, action) => {
        console.log("error", action.payload);
      });
  },
});

export default RecordSlice.reducer;

Here is my error:


What does state look like if you log it before state.lectures.push(action.payload)?

I suspect your getLectures.fulfilled case with state.lectures=action.payload; has changed your state.lectures invariant and it is no longer an array like you expect, and it's not until addLecture.fulfilled the invariant change is exposed. What is the state value when trying to add a lecture? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, including the UI code that is updating the state(s)?

You must behave state in react redux as immutable: instead of
state.lectures.push(action.payload)
use:
state.lectures={...state.lecture,action.payload}
or:
state={...state,lectures:{...state.lectures,action.payload}}

While generally you are correct that state must be immutable, redux toolkit uses Immer now to allow for mutation syntax without actually mutating state. So this will not solve the OPs error, which is actually related to the data type being wrong or unexpected

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice

Why change the state.lectures invariant from array to object? This doesn't make sense, does it? Also, Redux-Toolkit allows you to write mutable state updates since it is implemented over Immer.js.
